# Does Azure SQL Database supports encryption?

Tags: encryption, azure, azure-sql-database

I've read in multiples websites that Azure doesn't support encryption.

However I'm migrating (more like a backup) an Azure DB to SQL Server using the "Azure SQL Migration Tool" and I'm getting a warning about scripting the views: "Encrypted objects will not be scripted".

Also found this note in their site: Problem fixed in v3.5.5. Basically, Stored Procedures, Views, UDF, Triggers ... any object that can be encrypted is check before hand. The objects that are encrypted are highlighted in yellow with red letters. On the summary page, a list of encrypted objects that will not be scripted will be displayed.

http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/workitem/5762

If Azure SQL supports encryption, how can I get the creation script for this view?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I accepted David's answer since I've already tried different back-up / migration tools with the same result.  I don't have direct access to the DB but I think this might be the case where the SQL Server is running in a VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Azure SQL Database (database-as-a-service) does not support encryption. However: If you run SQL Server in a Virtual Machine, you should have all features at your disposal, including encryption.

I can't explain what's happening with the migration from SQL Database to SQL Server, regarding creation scripts involving encrypted objects on the target side.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Database still doesn't support encryption, so either you are reading from a SQL Server database, or there is a bug in the Wizard. There are no encrypted database objects in SQL Database as far as I know. If you are sure you are reading from SQL Database, just try creating an encrypted view in it and see what happens. From the MSDN documentation, creating an encrypted view is not supported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336244.aspx.

I am curious to know if you are getting the same error with Enzo Cloud Backup: http://www.bluesyntax.net/backup20.aspx.  Just use the free edition.